# Simple directive throwing errors

Tags: angularjs

I have written a simple directive to set focus on an element. 
However this directive seems to be giving me some errors.

```
app.directive('getFocus',['$timeout',function($timeout){

  return {
    link: function(scope,element,attrs){
      $timeout(function(){
        element.focus();
      },500);
    }

  };

}]);
```

Plnkr available here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/0x9GAqcTmerBmZMUiD3Y?p=info

Kindly advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not using jQuery, the Angular will use a built-in subset of jQuery: jqLite.
jqLite exposes a subset of the methods of jQuery (and `.focus()` is **not** available).
You can find more info in **[the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)**.

That said, `element` (as passed to the linking function of a directive) is not a raw DOM element, but one wrapped as a jQuery/jqLite object.

So, without jQuery you can't use `element.focus()`.
But you **can** use the native `.focus()` method of the DOM element: `element[0].focus()`

---

**[Updated demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/0J0Jz4HY94oixaYOXweI?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0):

element as passed into the link function is not the dom element, it's a wrapper around it.

You need to change that line to `element[0].focus();`
and that should work.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module("directiveApp", []);
app.controller("DirectiveController", function($scope) {
  $scope.name = "Shantha Moorthy.K";
});
app.directive("myName", function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    template: '<p>Shantha Moorthy K</p>'
  };
});
app.directive('helloWorld', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    replace: 'true',
    template: '<h5>Hello World!!!</h5>'
  };
});
app.directive('links', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    replace: true,
    template: '<p style="background-color:{{color}}">Link property examples.',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      elem.bind('click', function() {
        elem.css('background-color', 'white');
        scope.$apply(function() {
          scope.color = "white";
        });
      });
      elem.bind('mouseover', function() {
        elem.css('cursor', 'pointer');
      });
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="directiveApp">

<head>
  <title>Directives Examples</title>
</head>

<body ng-controller="DirectiveController">
  <h3>This is an attribute directive.</h3>
  <div my-name></div>
  <h3>This is an element directive to show the Hello World!!!</h3>
  <hello:world></hello:world>
  <h3>This directive example uses the link property inside the directive.</h3>
  <input type="text" ng-model="color" placeholder="Enter a color" />
  <links></links>
</body>

</html>
```